# .htaccess in subfolder for separate 404 page

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to have a separate 404 page for a subfolder of public_html. The .htaccess of the subfolder reads:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /subfolder/404.html
```

But 404 errors in the subfolder just come up as 500 Internal Server Errors, with the message

```
"Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."
```

I think this might be due to the mess of an .htaccess the root has. There's a Wordpress install in the root folder so this

```
# Use PHP5.4 Single php.ini as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54s .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# Set PHP handler to application/x-httpd-phpbeta on Mon Jan 11 15:10:53    MST 2016.
```

is what I get. I can't really make heads or tails of it, but why is it stopping my .htaccess from working?

Comment: Do you get a 500 error when you remove the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file? If not, it's probably not due to the root's `.htaccess` (which looks pretty normal for WordPress).

Comment: Yeah, i still do unfortunately.

Comment: So you're getting a 500 error for all requests that should be 404s, even when you delete your .htaccess file?

Comment: Yup. When the directory was created Bluehost had a host of default error pages (including 404) that worked, but I deleted them and now I just get generic 500 errors.